# Make image slide in from outside the screen HTML

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have an image slide in from the bottom, outside the screen, to cover the rest when I click this div:

```
<div class="brick" title="Brick Squad" alt="Brick Squad" onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor: pointer;" action="wall-in">
</div>
```

I want to use  HTML and CSS only please!

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.25%;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.opener > span {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: .3rem;
}

.opener > input {
    display: none;
}

.opener > input:checked ~ .img {
    top: 6rem !important;
}

.img {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    max-height: 100vh;
    top: 100%;
    transition: .6s;
}
```

```html
<label for="ooop" class="opener">
    <span>Toogle Me</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="ooop">
    <img class="img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/849835/pexels-photo-849835.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="">
</label>
```